# How to Redirect in React based on State

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, express-session

I'm using useEffect to get the login state of user if (userLoggedIn === false) then I want to redirect instantly to the login route, otherwise show the dashboard.

My problem is that the Dashboard is showing for a split second then the Redirecting happens! I tested the userLoggedIn in the console.log and it prints two times the first time the value is undefined, then it prints false...

I think this happening because the value of state is (userLoggedIn) is not set in the first place, but even when I set it to false for example it does the exact same thing..

I'm getting the (userLoggedIn) value using a useEffect from a backend, my code is: -

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import Axios from "axios";

import ModalNotFound from "../../components/Modal/ModalNotFound";

//views
import Home from "./views/Home";
import Menu from "./views/Menu";
import Orders from "./views/Orders";
import AddFood from "./views/AddFood";
import EditFood from "./views/EditFood";
import About from "./views/About";

const DashboardContainer = () => {
  document.body.classList.add("dashboard");

  const [userLoggedIn, setUserLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://dev.com:3001/login")
      .then(({ data }) => setUserLoggedIn(data.loggedIn))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));

    return () => setUserLoggedIn(); // cleanup: set the value to nothing
  }, []);

  console.log(userLoggedIn);

  return (
    <>
      {userLoggedIn === false ? (
        <Redirect to='/login' />
      ) : (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact strict path='/dashboard' component={Home} />
            {/* if user accesses /dashboard/ then remove ending slash / bcuz it messes the links*/}
            <Route exact strict path='/dashboard/'>
              <Redirect to='/dashboard' />
            </Route>
            <Route exact strict path='/dashboard/menu' component={Menu} />
            <Route exact strict path='/dashboard/orders' component={Orders} />
            <Route
              exact
              strict
              path='/dashboard/add-food'
              component={AddFood}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              strict
              path='/dashboard/edit-food'
              component={EditFood}
            />
            <Route exact strict path='/dashboard/about' component={About} />

            <Route path='*' component={ModalNotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default DashboardContainer;
```

and for the EndPoint/Back-end (http://dev.com:3001/login) I'm using this code: -

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.user) {
    res.send({ loggedIn: true, user: req.session.user });
  } else {
    res.send({ loggedIn: false });
  }
};
```

Comment: I suggest to use a splash screen / loader that covers the screen while API is fetching data. There will always be time (even of mili-seconds) between sending request and getting data. Hide Loader or splash only if userLoggedIn is true, so loading will he shown until redirected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said the console.log prints two times and the first time **userLoggedIn is undefined**. It's here that the dashboard is showing since **userLoggedIn is not equal to false** it goes to the code that displays the dashboard.

To prevent the first render, you can wrap your return

```
return (
        { userLoggedIn !== undefined && {/* your code */} }
       );
```